# Tag [stackoverflow.com] should be dropped

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, tag-synonyms

The [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com) tag does not seem to be of high value for categorizing, as most questions would be closed as off topic unless there are asking to duplicate functionality of the site. The body of the question already would mention the site so I am not sure what tagging the same will do.

In any case is there any value or situation that I am missing to keeping it?

Answer (score 1):

I think those questions should tag as **[stackexchange-engine](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-engine)** instead of [stackoverflow.com](/questions/tagged/stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Unfortunately that would take some of the benefit of the tag away (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not entirely sure where this text is displayed, it (the tag) may well still exist just so the following from the tag page can be displayed

> Please note that if you need to ask
>   questions about the site itself,
>   especially if you are looking for
>   support or reporting a bug, you should
>   do so on Meta Stack Overflow:
>   https://meta.stackoverflow.com/

If this text is displayed at some point whilst using this tag, users may well read it and go to meta instead...(although I have no idea whether this is actually happening)...

**Edit**
Perhaps if a user selects this tag when asking a question, this particular tag would trigger an inline display of this message...effectively allowing them to select the tag but never letting them actually ask the question with the tag...although they may well just remove the tag and ask anyway...at least they would have been warned...

**Edit also**
Can questions of the type "How does stackoverflow display an inline message" be tagged with this tag? would that make sense? this isn't appropriate to meta, is appropriate to SO and is about SO...but perhaps it doesn't need the tag as it could be how does yahoo, digg, wikipedia etc etc etc instead...and they don't all need there own tag.

Comment: Hmm ... it could be what is happening. I tried the tag and it was able to work(no warnings I did not submit though). As opposed to say a  subjective notice coming up when placing something in the title like "What is the best favourite most"

Answer (score 0):

I only found out about meta.stack overflow.com because someone bumped my question here.  I used 'stack overflow.com' as a tag.  Had a comment popped up like proposed above, I'd have known to move it myself.  Until then, I say the tag is needed because that's how others found my question to know to move it, and the keywords are what we're trained to use here.  So again, while I do say it's valid, I also agree it should prompt to allow us to move to meta ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I created this tag to disambiguate questions about a stackoverflow from questions about this site. The idea is that the prompt should direct inexperienced or unknowledgeable users from errantly using [stackoverflow]. This problem was much more pervasive a few months ago before the tag, and while I don't have any statistics, my anecdotal observation seems to reinforce my initial hypothesis.